# Write into char[] - terminated by signal 11 - sometimes

Tags: c, arrays, char, concatenation

I can't explain why the following code works most of the time, but fails every third, or second execution.

this is the part of my cunit test

```
assertTrue(io_register_output(consumer));
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    assertEquals(10, io_write("xxxxxxxxxx"));
}
io_flush();
printf("Result is: %s\n", result);
```

and this is `io_write`:

```
uint16_t io_write(char *data) {
    if (IOBuffer == NULL) return 0;
    uint16_t s = 0;

    while (*data != '\0') {
        IOBuffer->data[IOBuffer->write_position++] = *data;
        s += sizeof(*data);
        *data++;
        if (IOBuffer->write_position >= IO_BUFFER_SIZE){
            // buffer full, auto flush
            io_flush();
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

I write a `char*` into a buffer. If i call the function once, it works every time, but if a call it multiple times, it fails sometimes. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
from io_buffer.h:

```
#ifndef IO_BUFFER_SIZE
#define IO_BUFFER_SIZE      512
#endif
#ifndef IO_MAX_CONSUMER
#define IO_MAX_CONSUMER     8
#endif

typedef struct consumer {
     uint16_t    read_position;
     void        (*fn)(char *);
} IOBuffer_consumer_t;

typedef struct IOBuffer_s {
     uint16_t    count_consumer;
     uint16_t    write_position;
     char        data[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
     IOBuffer_consumer_t    consumer_arr[IO_MAX_CONSUMER]
} IOBuffer_t;

IOBuffer_t *IOBuffer;
```

And from io_buffer.c this are the two functions io_write and io_flush:

```
uint16_t io_write(char *data){
    if(IOBuffer == NULL) return 0;
    uint16_t s = 0;

    while(*data != '\0') {
        IOBuffer->data[IOBuffer->write_position++] = *data;
        s += sizeof(*data);
        data++;
        if(IOBuffer->write_position >= IO_BUFFER_SIZE){
            // buffer full, auto flush
            io_flush();
        }
    }
    return s;
}

void io_flush(void){
    for(uint8_t i=0; i < IOBuffer->count_consumer; ++i){
        IOBuffer_consumer_t *cPtr = &IOBuffer->consumer_arr[i];
        char *data =  IOBuffer->data;
        // fast forward
        data = data + cPtr->read_position;
        char *send = calloc(IOBuffer->write_position - cPtr->read_position, sizeof(char));

        // concat charakters
        while(cPtr->read_position != IOBuffer->write_position ){
            sprintf(send, "%s%c", send, *data );
            ++cPtr->read_position;
            ++data;
        }
       cPtr->fn(send);
       cPtr->read_position = 0;
       free(send);
    }
    IOBuffer->write_position = 0;
}
```

The purpose is to register multiple "consumers" to send the output to. It is a cu unittest running on Mac OS at the moment to prepare some code for uCs's. Depending on a configuration i want to send the output to uart, display, or - in test mode on my mac - to a testroutine, like:

```
char *result;
void *consumer(char *in){
    sprintf(result, "%s", in);
    printf("consumer-1-get: %s\n", result);
}
```

from my unittest.

Again, the error occures not all the time, but very often if i am write the second or third time into io_write. <strike>Even io_flush will never called.</strike>

Edit 2:
Found out that the bug is somewhere is io_flush(), that is called from withhin the unittest.

Comment: Your code could use some formatting.

Comment: Where do you reset write position or set it at all?

Comment: You're writing outside of your buffer and overwriting something else. The code you've included is insufficient to debug it precisely. If you're on a Linux type system, Valgrind may be a useful tool for you to resolve this with.

Comment: It looks like you want data++; instead of *data++;

Comment: Are you sure you need to dereference data together with applying post-increment?

Comment: @danf, it will do the same but yeah, it should be clearer.

Comment: you need to do something to reset "write_position" in between calls.  And like danf said, ``*data++;`` is wrong

Comment: @PeterShaw At the risk of making your question a lot bigger (your conciseness is appreciated but we need more to help), could you please include code for `io_flush();` and the definition of `IOBuffer` global and its struct definition.

Comment: @PeterShaw As far as I can tell the error is not in this code. Is this running on a microcontroller? If so, then it could be an interrupt that is causing you headaches. Where else do you use the `IOBuffer`?

Comment: Hi,and thanks for your answers. I Fixed the *data++ section, but still have the same issue. io_flush() will not executed, because the IO_BUFFER_SIZE is far bigger than this 20 chars. I will add the definition above.

Comment: AH! The error occurs not in io_write, but in the io_flush from the test. Hm, thanks a lot guys. i am a step further.